# Can't ping Ubuntu16.04 from Windows 10 (or vice-versa) over direct ethernet connection

Tags: networking, ethernet

Yesterday ifconfig brought up an 'eth0', along with IP addresses etc that allowed me to use PuTTY to use an Ubuntu machine remotely.

Today that's gone, and there are "eno1" and "eno2" options instead (which I think were there before, but not sure). ifconfig provided no address from either, so I've added both in on /etc/network/interfaces, providing the same gateway address both to them and to the windows pc.
EDIT:

```
 dmesg | grep eth0
```

shows that eth0 was renamed eno1

I still can't ping the Linux box from the pc, nor vice-versa. The message displayed is "Destination Host Unreachable"

Both computers are connected directly by an Ethernet cable - can't connect either to a wider network for company security reasons.

Does anyone know how to either bring back eth0 or use one of the eno adapters to establish a connection?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled any firewall?

Comment: @SandeepC It should be configured to let the connection through. Turned it off completely and tried again, still nothing